# Detecting language of a text document other than using iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am working on a problem where I have to detect any non-English documents and remove them.

There have been some questions with similar problems here. And even though the presented solutions mostly work just fine, I still wonder if there is a faster way to do this.

My code so far has been like this (I use [langdetect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/langdetect) which is a Python package that does this).

```
from langdetect import detect

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    review = row['reviewText']
    lang = detect(str(review))
    if lang!='en':
        df.drop(i, inplace=True)
```

As I said, the code above works just fine.

It wouldn't really be a problem when you have a small set of data. But when you are working on hundreds of thousands of data items, or even millions, it's just really slow and inefficient.

The `iterrows()` doesn't seem to be the right approach for this kind of problem. Is there any other solution for this?

As for a side note, I only need to check English documents anyway, I don't need to know what language every document is written in.

To put it simply, I will remove any document not written in English. So I also wonder if using the `langdetect` package is the best approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like we can using apply here

```
df[df.reviewText.apply(lambda x : detect(x))=='en']
```

Comment: @jdehesa I think df.reviewText is series